# Removing a python module from $pythonpath

Tags: python

Is there any way to 'uninstall' a module from the python path other than removing the files manually?

Pip, easy_install, setuptools etc all have install options, but no remove options!

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` supports uninstall.

> pip is able to uninstall most installed packages with

```
pip uninstall package-name
```

> Known exceptions include pure-distutils packages installed with python setup.py install (such packages leave behind no metadata allowing determination of what files were installed), and script wrappers installed by develop-installs (python setup.py develop).
>
> pip also performs an automatic uninstall of an old version of a package before upgrading to a newer version, so outdated files (and egg-info data) from conflicting versions aren’t left hanging around to cause trouble. The old version of the package is automatically restored if the new version fails to download or install.

See http://pip.openplans.org/

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't update Pip for a year or so, it didn't have it back then.